# How do I get global variables of React Native runtime in the console?

Tags: react-native, google-chrome-devtools

I'm following this article: https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/blob/master/docs/debugger-integration.md#debugging-tips

specifically I want to be able to see values stored in AsyncStorage in the console. The article says that I need to use "showAsyncStorageContentInDev()" somehow, but I don't understand where I need to write that. Can anyone explain what the instructions in that article mean? Do I have to include showAsyncStorageContentInDev() in the RNDebuggerWorker.js file?

Thanks!

Comment: Try just typing that function call in the console

Comment: @Kai that gives me "Uncaught ReferenceError: showAsyncStorageContentInDev is not defined"

Comment: If you search for that function in the source, you can see that it's added to the global object: https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/blob/04db26a283532966a55ddb9ecdd7dd3615b1e6d1/app/worker/devMenu.js
so you should be able to call it and log the return value anywhere in your code.

Comment: There's a context switcher in the devtools console toolbar.

Comment: @Kai it's working, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I met this same issue and solved it by adding/installing react devtools in my project:

`yarn add --dev react-devtools` or with npm `npm i -D react-devtools`
You can also install it globally if you need it in most of your projects.